# How to run a Webapp on one EC2 instance and computation app on another EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I need to build an application which auto scales EC2 instances. For this I have a Webapp running a PHP code to take it in the client input. This input needs to fed into an SQS queue. Another EC2 instance called the compute machine will read this input from the queue and processes the result. This result should be mapped to the client input and displayed by the webapp instance. I want to how this can be achieved. Any ideas or pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but my suggestion is to use two ELB. connect the webapp ec2 to outer elb, when you auto scale the ec2 you just have to connect it with outer ELB, the outer ELB is allow to interact with the internet(clients). Connect the compute machine ec2 to inner ELB, communication between ec2 will be through ELB address and port.